# Plot Multiple lines in Python from CSV

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, plot, line

I am trying to plot the growth of sales on a per-city basis over time. I have a csv file that I'm importing with pandas...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt    
df = pd.read_csv("filepath.csv")
```

In that dataframe are three columns, date (formatted m/d/yyyy 0:00:00), order value, and city.

I'm trying to plot the occurance of orders in each city as a separate line, such that the first date there's an order for a particular city, the y value will be 1, the second date there's an order for that city, the y value will be two, etc.

I also need the code to ignore null values for City.

So far I've come up with this:

```
style.use('ggplot')

df.groupby('City').plot(x='Date', y='Weekly Payment')

plt.title('Title of Chart')
plt.ylabel('Y Axis')
plt.xlabel('X Axis')

plt.show()
```

It returns an error saying there is no numeric data to plot. Help much appreciated!

edit: here is an image of the kind of graph I'd like to create:

[image: image on imgur]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've added a link to an image of the type of output I'd like to see.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you're having is that you don't have the same ammount of data for all cities,

In order for information to be plotted in the same figure, the data sets need to be the same size for every plot. So what you need to do is generate dummy data to fill in the gaps where data is missing for your second plot.

As for ignoring null cities a simple try and except wrapper should do it.

Comment: Hmm, what kind of dummy data can I apply that won't mess with the accuracy of the report? Also, where would you apply the except wrapper to ignore null values?

Comment: You can try to figure out how many datapoints are missing inbetween real data and plot points on the graph that connects the two adjacent real data points, if that makes sense.

As for the try and except, figure out which line or snippet returns an error from null cities and wrap it between a try and except statement

Comment: Another thing you may want to consider, is whether or not a line graph is appropriate here. Have you considered using bar graphs? If a payment was made for one city on a given date but no payment was made for the other, my previous suggestion would show a graph that may be misleading, but a bar graph would show a blank space, which is probably more representative, although I suppose I am making assumptions about your use case